# What first? SSD or Win8

Tags: windows-8, ssd

I currently am running Win7 - 64 bit.  Looking to upgrade to Win8 (64 bit) as well as switch my boot drive to an SSD.  Which one should I do first?  Does it matter?

If it makes any different, my motherboard is an ASUS P6T deluxe, and my new SSD is an OCZ Vertex 4 256 GB.

Thanks,

GS

Comment: SSD!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Install the SSD first . . . no point installing Windows to the old drive, then doing it again 
to the SSD.

**Edit:** By definition, if you install the OS to the existing drive, the SSD will not be your boot drive.  I've never tried upgrading the OS to another drive; not sure if that's even possible?

In any case, the only reason not to do a clean install is if you have programs that you can't/don't want to reinstall.  If that's the case, I'd use clonezilla or similar to clone the existing drive to the SSD, then run the Win 8 upgrade.

Otherwise, you can leave the existing drive untouced, add the SSD, and install Windows 8 there, making sure to boot off of that drive.  You can then access the existing drive as a data drive, and get any files/data off there that you'll need.

Comment: Note that this is NOT a clean install, it is an upgrade.  Why would I have to install twice regardless of which route I go?

Comment: If you don't install the SSD first, then you'll either need to clone the drive to the SSD after you install the upgrade, or just install Windows to the SSD to make the SSD your boot drive.